# Multibyte characters stored with utf_unicode_ci collation do not display correctly on web page

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter, utf-8

I have set the collation of my field of a `VARCHAR(250)` to `utf8_unicode_ci`. I insert my record in phpMyAdmin with slovakia character and after that when view back in the database, it shows everything fine. But when I tried to query and get the result from my php script, it shows me "PokutovanÃ½ sa rozhodne…". I tried to get the character code of the returning data and it's really a "?" character and not browser characterset problem. besides, I also echoed this line in my page "". no success. Any idea how to solve it.

I am using CodeIgniter and MySQL. In my config file

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

In the database config file I have

```
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

In the controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        //echo $this->session->userdata('AppLanguage');
        $this->config->set_item('language', $this->session->userdata('AppLanguage'));
        $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    }
```

Comment: Do you set your encoding to UTF8 in your html (view) like so: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">?    Also when you save file in your text editor, make sure they are have 'UTF8 without BOM' encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with CodeIgniter a while back. In the `CI_DB_Driver` class (`/system/database/DB_Driver.php`), there is a `db_set_charset()` function that is called upon initialization of the class. I commented out the function call and it fixed the problem.